# How to assign dynamic ID to label control inside DataList item template?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0

I have a DataList control which is bound by SQLDataSource. The data source is fetching two column values, viz: ID, Name.

The DataList ItemTemplate looks like this:

```
<DataList>
   <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval(Name) %>' />
   </ItemTemplate>
</DataList>
```

I want the Label ID to be bound to the first column like:

```
<asp:Label ID='<%# Eval(ID) %> ...../>
```

But it gives error that ID should be simple.

Is there any way to use Eval value to generate assign to Label ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign it using data binding but you can access the ClientID and use that else were.

```
<label for='<%# Container.FindControl("TargetControlID").ClientID %>'>
    Label Text
</label>
<asp:Label ID="TargetControlID" runat="server" Text="Target Control" />
```

Comment: I want ID part and not Text Part. Text is coming via another column, ID I want from another column.

Comment: Updated the answer. Take a look.

Comment: Trying out let me see. Do I need to include both simple HTML label control and server control?

Comment: From your question, I wasn't able to deduce exactly what you are trying to accomplish. If you need the ID to use else were, my code should work for you.

Comment: Yup seems to be working but I want to check what ID it is generating for each Label server control in the ItemBound event.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is this. I want to display Labels one below the other with some text on it. But these labels should be listed via DataList as Label Text and Label ID both coming from a table. Now when user clicks on any Label, that ID I want to use while calling a stored procedure.

Comment: If you want to bind a value and then pass that back to server side logic, consider using a Button or LinkButton control with the CommandName / CommandArgument values set via binding. Wire up the OnCommandClick event and retrieve the one or both of those values in the server side event call. The ControlID property is not intended to be a method by which you can pass a client side value back to the server.

Comment: Is it possible to make use of hidden fields to achieve this?